# libssh2: libssh2_channel_write() doesn't seem to write data on the channel

Tags: c, passwords, send, libssh2

I am trying to execute a command on a router via ssh. After the login, when I execute the command on the device, it asks for an additional password. I am not able to send the password using `libssh2_channel_write()`. Here is the code snippet (modified the `ssh2_exec.c` that comes with the library). This is a snippet where the device is authenticated and the command has been issued. This loop just tries to get read the output of the executed command:

```
for( ;; )
{
    /* loop until we block */
    int rc;
    do
    {
        char buffer[0x4000];
        rc = libssh2_channel_read( channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer) );

        if( rc > 0 )
        {
            int i;
            char *enable = "stic-isr2951-t1";
            int ret;
            bytecount += rc;
            fprintf(stderr, "We read [%d] bytes:\n", bytecount);
            for( i=0; i < rc; ++i )
                fputc( buffer[i], stderr);
            **if ( strstr(buffer, "assword:") != NULL ){
                fprintf(stderr, "Sending the additional password now\n");
                ret = libssh2_channel_write(channel, enable, strlen(enable));
                fprintf(stderr, "Wrote [%d] bytes\n", ret);
            }**
        }
        else {
            if( rc != LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN )
                /* no need to output this for the EAGAIN case */
                fprintf(stderr, "libssh2_channel_read returned %d\n", rc);
        }
    }
    while( rc > 0 );

    /* this is due to blocking that would occur otherwise so we loop on
       this condition */
    if( rc == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN )
    {
        waitsocket(sock, session);
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

In the snippet above, the code that detects that the device is posting a password prompt is:

```
   if ( strstr(buffer, "assword:") != NULL ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Sending the additional password now\n");
        ret = libssh2_channel_write(channel, enable, strlen(enable));
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrote [%d] bytes\n", ret);
    }
```

That's where I have a problem. The password being sent on the channel isn't working as the device continues to timeout expecting the password. There is no indication that `libssh2_channel_write()` failed as the return value says it wrote the password properly.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

The problem with the continuous timeout password prompted was because the password didn't have `\n` at the end. I was expecting the lib to take care of it but it didn't.

Now that I am able to send the password to the remote device, I run into another issue. After I send the password via `libssh2_channel_write()`, subsequent `libssh2_channel_read()` fails with

> LIBSSH2_ERROR_SOCKET_RECV

I am not sure why is this happening. Logic was to check if the `libssh2_channel_write()` was successful by doing a subsequent `read()` (which would give the command prompt on the remote device) and then issue the command to be executed on the remote device followed by a subsequent read to get the command output. Am I doing something wrong? This doesn't seem to be working. Here's the complete code snippet:

```
/*
 * Sample showing how to use libssh2 to execute a command remotely.
 *
 * The sample code has fixed values for host name, user name, password
 * and command to run.
 *
 * Run it like this:
 *
 * $ ./ssh2_exec 127.0.0.1 user password "uptime"
 *
 */ 


#include "libssh2_config.h"
#include <libssh2.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifdef HAVE_WINSOCK2_H
#include <winsock2.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H
#include <sys/socket.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_NETINET_IN_H
#include <netinet/in.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H
#include <sys/select.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_ARPA_INET_H
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static int waitsocket(int socket_fd, LIBSSH2_SESSION *session)
{
    struct timeval timeout;
    int rc;
    fd_set fd;
    fd_set *writefd = NULL;
    fd_set *readfd = NULL;
    int dir;

    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    FD_ZERO(&fd);

    FD_SET(socket_fd, &fd);

    /* now make sure we wait in the correct direction */ 
    dir = libssh2_session_block_directions(session);


    if(dir & LIBSSH2_SESSION_BLOCK_INBOUND)
        readfd = &fd;

    if(dir & LIBSSH2_SESSION_BLOCK_OUTBOUND)
        writefd = &fd;

    rc = select(socket_fd + 1, readfd, writefd, NULL, &timeout);

    return rc;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *hostname = "10.10.10.10";
    const char *commandline = "show version";
    const char *username    = "user1";
    const char *password    = "password1";
    unsigned long hostaddr;
    int flag = 0;
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    const char *fingerprint;
    LIBSSH2_SESSION *session;
    LIBSSH2_CHANNEL *channel;
    int rc;
    int exitcode;
    char *exitsignal=(char *)"none";
    int bytecount = 0;
    size_t len;
    LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOSTS *nh;
    int type;

    if (argc > 1)
        /* must be ip address only */ 
        hostname = argv[1];

    if (argc > 2) {
        username = argv[2];
    }
    if (argc > 3) {
        password = argv[3];
    }
    if (argc > 4) {
        commandline = argv[4];
    }

    rc = libssh2_init (0);

    if (rc != 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "libssh2 initialization failed (%d)\n", rc);
        return 1;
    }

    hostaddr = inet_addr(hostname);
    printf("host address is: %ld\n", hostaddr);

    /* Ultra basic "connect to port 22 on localhost"
     * Your code is responsible for creating the socket establishing the
     * connection
     */ 
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(22);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = hostaddr;
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)(&sin),
                sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to connect!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Create a session instance */ 
    session = libssh2_session_init();

    if (!session)
        return -1;

    //libssh2_trace(session, LIBSSH2_TRACE_AUTH|LIBSSH2_TRACE_SOCKET);

    /* tell libssh2 we want it all done non-blocking */ 
    libssh2_session_set_blocking(session, 0);


    /* ... start it up. This will trade welcome banners, exchange keys,
     * and setup crypto, compression, and MAC layers
     */ 
    while ((rc = libssh2_session_handshake(session, sock)) ==

           LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN);
    if (rc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failure establishing SSH session: %d\n", rc);
        return -1;
    }

    nh = libssh2_knownhost_init(session);

    if(!nh) {
        /* eeek, do cleanup here */ 
        return 2;
    }

    /* read all hosts from here */ 
    libssh2_knownhost_readfile(nh, "known_hosts",

                               LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_FILE_OPENSSH);

    /* store all known hosts to here */ 
    libssh2_knownhost_writefile(nh, "dumpfile",

                                LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_FILE_OPENSSH);

    fingerprint = libssh2_session_hostkey(session, &len, &type);

    if(fingerprint) {
        struct libssh2_knownhost *host;
#if LIBSSH2_VERSION_NUM >= 0x010206
        /* introduced in 1.2.6 */ 
        int check = libssh2_knownhost_checkp(nh, hostname, 22,

                                             fingerprint, len,
                                             LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_TYPE_PLAIN|
                                             LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_KEYENC_RAW,
                                             &host);
#else
        /* 1.2.5 or older */ 
        int check = libssh2_knownhost_check(nh, hostname,

                                            fingerprint, len,
                                            LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_TYPE_PLAIN|
                                            LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_KEYENC_RAW,
                                            &host);
#endif
        fprintf(stderr, "Host check: %d, key: %s\n", check,
                (check <= LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_CHECK_MISMATCH)?
                host->key:"<none>");

        /*****
         * At this point, we could verify that 'check' tells us the key is
         * fine or bail out.
         *****/ 
    }
    else {
        /* eeek, do cleanup here */ 
        return 3;
    }
    libssh2_knownhost_free(nh);


    if ( strlen(password) != 0 ) {
        /* We could authenticate via password */ 
        while ((rc = libssh2_userauth_password(session, username, password)) ==

               LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN);
        if (rc) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Authentication by password failed.\n");
            goto shutdown;
        }
    }
    else {
        /* Or by public key */ 
        while ((rc = libssh2_userauth_publickey_fromfile(session, username,

                                                         "/home/user/"
                                                         ".ssh/id_rsa.pub",
                                                         "/home/user/"
                                                         ".ssh/id_rsa",
                                                         password)) ==
               LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN);
        if (rc) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\tAuthentication by public key failed\n");
            goto shutdown;
        }
    }

#if 1
    //libssh2_trace(session, ~0 );

#endif

    /* Exec non-blocking on the remove host */ 
    while( (channel = libssh2_channel_open_session(session)) == NULL &&

           libssh2_session_last_error(session,NULL,NULL,0) ==

           LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN )
    {
        waitsocket(sock, session);
    }
    if( channel == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error\n");
        exit( 1 );
    }

    while( (rc = libssh2_channel_exec(channel, commandline)) ==

           LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN )
    {
        waitsocket(sock, session);
    }
    if( rc != 0 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error\n");
        exit( 1 );
    }
    for( ;; )
    {
        /* loop until we block */ 
        int rc;
        do
        {
            char buffer[0x4000];
            rc = libssh2_channel_read( channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer) );

            if( rc > 0 )
            {
                int i;
                char *enable = "check-password\n";
                int ret;
                bytecount += rc;
                fprintf(stderr, "We read [%d] bytes:\n", bytecount);
                fputc('[', stderr);
                for( i=0; i < rc; ++i )
                    fputc( buffer[i], stderr);
                fputc(']', stderr);

                if ( strstr(buffer, "Password:") != NULL ){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Sending the password now\n");
                    while((ret = libssh2_channel_write(channel, enable, strlen(enable))) == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN) {
                        printf("ERROR_EAGAIN - sending password again\n");
                    }

                    fprintf(stderr, "Wrote [%d] bytes: \n", ret);
                    flag = 1;
                    continue;
                }
                if (!flag){ // start
                    char *cmd = "show clock\n";
                    int ret;
                    fprintf(stderr, "THIS is Fetching show clock command now\n");
                    while((ret = libssh2_channel_write(channel, cmd, strlen(cmd))) == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN) {
                        printf("ERROR_EAGAIN - sending show clock again\n");
                    }
                    flag = 1;
                } // end
            }
            else {
                if(rc != LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN)
                    fprintf(stderr, "libssh2_channel_read returned [%d]:\n ", rc);
            }
        }
        while( rc > 0 );

        /* this is due to blocking that would occur otherwise so we loop on
           this condition */ 
        if( rc == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN )
        {
            int check;
            check = waitsocket(sock, session);
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    exitcode = 127;
    while( (rc = libssh2_channel_close(channel)) == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN )

        waitsocket(sock, session);

    if( rc == 0 )
    {
        exitcode = libssh2_channel_get_exit_status( channel );

        libssh2_channel_get_exit_signal(channel, &exitsignal,

                                        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }

    if (exitsignal)
        fprintf(stderr, "\nGot signal: %s\n", exitsignal);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "\nEXIT: %d bytecount: %d\n", exitcode, bytecount);

    libssh2_channel_free(channel);

    channel = NULL;

shutdown:

    libssh2_session_disconnect(session,

                               "Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing");
    libssh2_session_free(session);


#ifdef WIN32
    closesocket(sock);
#else
    close(sock);
#endif
    fprintf(stderr, "all done\n");

    libssh2_exit();


    return 0;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The problem with continuous password timeouts happened to be the '\n' missing at the end of the password. i was assuming that the library took care of it but wasn't.

Comment: But i have a different issue now - i have edited and re-posted the question